# How can I get GHC to generate instances of Data.Typeable for GADTs with Typeable in the context?

Tags: haskell, ghc, gadt, derived-instances

Suppose I have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DeriveDataTypeable, StandaloneDeriving #-}
import Data.Typeable

class Eq t => OnlyEq t
class (Eq t, Typeable t) => BothEqAndTypeable t

data Wrapper a where
    Wrap :: BothEqAndTypeable a => a -> Wrapper a

deriving instance Eq (Wrapper a)
deriving instance Typeable1 Wrapper
```

Then, the following instance declaration works, *without* a constraint on `t`:

```
instance OnlyEq (Wrapper t)
```

and does what I expect it to do.

---

But the following instance declaration doesn't work:

```
instance BothEqAndTypeable (Wrapper t)
```

since GHC - I'm using 7.6.1 - complains that:

```
No instance for (Typeable t)
  arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
Possible fix:
  add (Typeable t) to the context of the instance declaration
In the instance declaration for `BothEqAndTypeable (Wrapper t)'
```

Adding `Typeable t` to the context works, of course. But so does adding the following instance:

```
instance Typeable (Wrapper t) where
    typeOf (Wrap x) = typeOf1 (Wrap x) `mkAppTy` typeOf x
```

Is there a way to get GHC to write this latter instance for me? If so, how? If not, why not?

I was hoping GHC would be able to pull the `Typeable` constraint from the context on the `Wrap` constructor, just as it did with the `Eq` constraint.
I think that my problems boils down to the fact that GHC explicitly disallows writing `deriving instance Typeable (Wrapper t)`, and the standard `(Typeable1 s, Typeable a) => Typeable (s a)` instance can't 'look inside' `s a` to find a `Typeable a` dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was hoping GHC would be able to pull the `Typeable` constraint from the context on the `Wrap` constructor

If it had a `Wrap` constructor, it could pull the `Typeable` constraint from it.

But it doesn't have a `Wrap` constructor.

The difference is that the `Eq` instance uses the value, so it's either a `Wrap something`, where the `Wrap` constructor makes the `Eq` dictionary for the wrapped type available, and everything is fine, or it's `⊥`, and then everything is fine too, evaluating `x == y` bottoms out.

Note that the derived

```
instance Eq (Wrapper a)
```

does *not* have an `Eq` constraint on the type variable `a`.

```
Prelude DerivT> (undefined :: Wrapper (Int -> Int)) == undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
Prelude DerivT> (undefined :: (Int -> Int)) == undefined

<interactive>:3:29:
    No instance for (Eq (Int -> Int)) arising from a use of `=='
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Eq (Int -> Int))
    In the expression: (undefined :: Int -> Int) == undefined
    In an equation for `it':
        it = (undefined :: Int -> Int) == undefined
```

But the `Typeable` instance must not make use of the value, so there's no bottoming out if the supplied value isn't a `Wrap something`.

Thus the derived `instance Typeable1 Wrapper` supplies

```
instance Typeable t => Typeable (Wrapper t)
```

but not an unconstrained

```
instance Typeable (Wrapper t)
```

and that unconstrained instance cannot be derived by GHC.

Hence you have to either provide a constrained

```
instance Typeable t => BothEqAndTypeable (Wrapper t)
```

or an unconstrained

```
instance Typeable (Wrapper t)
```

yourself.

Comment: Right, I keep forgetting about the finer points of `undefined` as I usually store something in my datatypes :-) I think I need some sort of `newtype` GADTs, then! And an additional question, if I may: is the unconstrained `Typeable (Wrapper t)` instance I wrote in any way bad, provided I don't care that `typeOf (error "aargh" :: Wrapper Bool)` bottoms out?

Comment: Well, it's a slightly surprising instance since you can't use it with `undefined :: Wrapper Bool` like other `Typeable` instances. If you make that public, at least put a warning on it. But I don't think that should necessarily stop you. In future GHC releases, however - methinks from 7.8 onwards, all `Typeable` instances will be provided by GHC, and for all types, iirc. So you won't have to deal with such problems then.

Comment: Looking at the repository, you'll need `-XAutoDeriveTypeable`. Cool! I think I *might* just go and clone 7.8.1 over the weekend for that, but the last time I built GHC was in 2002 (early 6.x cycle?), so that's a bit scary... But thanks again!